# How to list all selectable tables with current user in SAP HANA DB

Tags: sql, hana

I want to list all tables with current user using sql.

I know there are some way to get privileges, like `EFFECTIVE_PRIVILEGES`, but it only shows privileges which is granted by `GRANT SELECT ~ on [TABLE] to [USERS]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the schema information to get this - there's no SHOW TABLES or equivalent available.

Try:

```sql
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM "SYS"."TABLES" WHERE SCHEMA_NAME='<database_name>'
```

which works for me.

You can also get Column Names in thsi way from the SYS.COLUMNS view

Comment: Thanks. I thought that "SYS"."TABLES" will shows all available tables, are all available tables selectable in HANA DB? In Oracle, I saw some accessible tables that can't use select.